# C# .NET - Adding DLL as reference won't work

Tags: c#, .net, api, dll, sdk

I am trying to add a DLL as a reference to my project (64bit on VS2010 with the .NET Framework 4). But I am getting the following error:

> A reference to 'XXX' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assemlby or COM component

Installing the DLL with RegSvr32 says:

> The module was loaded but the entry-point DLLRegisterServer was not found...

Trying installing the DLL with RegAsm says:

> error RA0000: "XXX" could'nt be loaded, because it's no valid .NET Assembly.

I have no idea hwat kind of DLL that is, but that it is contained inside a SDK which was written for the .NET Framework and in C#.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds like it's not a COM component or a managed dll. What does [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com) say about this file? Maybe it's a native library and you have to use pinvoke

Comment: @DennisKuypers Dependency Walker couldn't even load the dll. It said the following: Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.

Comment: Even though Dependency Walker threw the error, it states the following in the gui:
- XXX.dll
 * KERNEL32.DLL
 * USER32.DLL
 * MSVCP90.DLL
 * WS2_32.DLL
 * MSVCR90.DLL

Comment: That is not an error per se - but from MSVCP (Microsoft Visual C Plusplus/Runtime) you can see that it is a C/C++ native dll and you have to use pinvoke

Comment: @DennisKuypers I will! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my english:

either the dll is dll building for c# (managed) and you have just to add reference to your project : (right click on reference and  select "add reference") -> you have to indicate where is locating your dll. After when you need to access at your Dll, you have to include the namespace.

either is not a dll building for c# you have to load the dll by using loadlibray

either your dll is corrupted..